# Is there some webconsole for titan-1.0.0

Tags: titan, gremlin-server

guys. I'm looking for some webconsole component for Titan-1.0.0, something looks like dogHouse for previous version of Titan.  For titan-1.0.0, Gremlin Server takes over it. But it's not very friendly to users. So  is there some alternative tools? Thanks. 
PS: I also found that there is a gelphi plugin for Gremlin server, but the document is so unclear that I even can not know how to make it happen. I will
be very appreciated for the detail steps. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want a visualization tool of some sort. Aside from commercial tools like [KeyLines](https://cambridge-intelligence.com/keylines/titan/) and [Linkurious](http://linkurio.us/), I don't think you'll find much else. I would like to know why you find Gremlin Server "not very friendly" (though it is not a visualization tool and has no UI) and why you found the gephi plugin docs "unclear". btw, the gephi plugin is for Gremlin Console not Gremlin Server (it is not a server-side plugin).

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. The tools like KeyLines and Linkurious are awesome, but I think they are not what I really need, because I want to it can execute gremlin codes and show results(if can be visulizied, better) .I find gremlin server is not friendly because of no UI and also because the configuration file is too complicated and has no guide infomations, especially for a fresher.

Comment: I thought gephi plugin docs is uncear for the reason that I only find several sentences("The following instructions assume that Gephi has been download and installed. It further assumes that the Graph Streaming plugin has been installed (Tools > Plugins)." [link]( http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/reference/#gephi-plugin) ), I think a step-by-step operate document is neeed here. And I still think the plugin is for Gremlin Server. I would like you and your collegues can update the webpages, help us to use titan more conviniently. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry, I have sensed my fault. The Gephi plugin is definitly for Gremlin Console not Gremlin Server. But I still confused with the configuration of Gremlin Server. In our project, Titan is embedded in the application, so i do not want to start another titan instance, and if the gremlin server can operate the graph if only have gremlin server installed and configuration changed(without install titan)?  Thanks. @stephen mallette

Comment: Thank you for the feedback on the documentation. Documentation of every item in the Gremlin Server config file can be found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/reference/#_configuring_2) - were you looking for something more? As for Gephi docs, Gephi is not a TinkerPop project and re-writing their documentation on how to install Gephi or use its plugin system is beyond the scope of TinkerPop documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand your question in the last comment. Gremlin Server does require a Graph instance. It can't know anything about your Titan instance without it. You make that sound as if that is a problem, but I don't understand why. Perhaps you can rephrase your question.

Comment: Thanks for your direction which has helped me a lot. My collegue and I want to build a graph DB for analying data(community relations), and want   it can be used by our algorithm engineers who knows little about system architecture and Java. So we try to find some webconsole, which can help them execute the gremlin command conviniently. My collegue build a web project, which contains titan.jar, and you know start the web project will create a titan-instance(The other way of start a titan instance is to download titan-1.0.0-hadoop.zip and execute titan.sh).

Comment: So if I install Gremlin-Server alone(just downloading gremlin-server and starting it), did it can connect to the Titan-instance which my collegue created before? Or, only start the Gremlin-Server can start a new Titan instance with the same configuration of ES and Hbase that we configured for the titan-instance created before? Thanks.

Comment: You can download Gremlin Server alone and configure it to connect to an existing Titan database that was created elsewhere. Just provide Gremlin Server the same configuration you used to create that original Titan instance. It is just my opinion, but if your colleague is just doing analysis, I think that using the Gremlin Console and Gephi is the best solution. Those two tools are perfect for that use case.

Comment: @stephen mallette Thanks very much, what you said worked! Now we are trying to use Gremlin Console and Gelphi~ I'm very grateful for your patience.